# Метка для фреймворка Phaser

Tags: предложение, метки, создание-метки

Несколько раз на ruSO видел вопросы по [данному фреймворку](http://phaser.io/)

[Развернуть в phaserJS спрайт зеркально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394364/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-phaserjs-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519043/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-phaser-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC

Вопросов не много, и, возможно, не такие суперглобальные, как про Jquery/php и менее популярное, чем на enSO, но, думаю, неплохо бы добавить метку для него.

Вот [она же на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phaser-framework/info)

`Phaser` - это javascript-фреймворк, предназначенный для разработки игр для десктопных и мобильных приложений.

Comment: Почему бы и нет. Предлагаю начать с описания будущей метки. (Создать-то вы и так её можете )

Comment: @NickVolynkin видимо мне тоже надо справку читать)))) видимо я уже ненароком создал ей когда в вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519043/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-phaser-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC   добавил)))  Можно закрывать вопрос?  ахах)

Comment: @NickVolynkin добавил описание http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/phaser-framework/info   которое наверное кому-то надо будет чуть подредачить)